# Getting user location with form submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hello im using HTML5 geolocation and after the user submits the form i want to store his longtitude and latitude but a problem has appeared

i made an onclick="" event on the submit button and when the button is pressed js will get the coordinations and put them to hidden fields in the form and the form will be sent to the php but , whenever i submit the form , the small popup will come out and it asks for permission to get the location and it imediately dissapears thats probably because of the php that refreshed the page , what should i do ? as i already said when you click the submit form button js will be triggered and will ask for permission after the permission is accepted the hidden fields will be filled with the coordination data and then the form will be sent to the server but , after i press the button then the popup about allowing the location will go out for one second and imediately dissapear and the page will refresh with no result , how can i fix this ?

Comment: you should first deny the form from beeing send (`e.preventDefault()`), than wait untill the user grands the permissions...or may deny and than handle on his inputs

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to solve this is to run the JS code that detects the location and asks for permission when the form first *loads* in the page, not when it's *submitted*.

Your issue is that you're trying to execute javascript simultaneously as the form submits. Unless your override the default behaviour, the form will submit anyway regardless of what scripts are run in the onclick event, and it will not wait for them.

The other way is to override the default submit behaviour. Assuming you have jQuery loaded, handle the click like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#mySubmitButton").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //stops the form from submitting
    //here write the code which asks for the location and puts it in the hidden fields
   $("#myForm").submit(); //only now do we submit the form, manually.
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

*As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure contexts such as HTTPS. If
your site is hosted on an non-secure origin (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users
location will no longer work.